# Count times same value is in array

Tags: php

I have a question,

If i have the following array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Apple 
[1] => Apple
[3] => Banana
[4] => Apple 
)
```

Is there a way to count how many times the same value occurs in the array?

So in this example how many times Apple occurs in the array.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: have you searched before asking?

Comment: If you want to count items, use `count`...

Comment: @Hearner `array_count_values()` function already available to count each value in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP **[array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)** function.

```
array_count_values($your_array);

<?php
    $array = array("Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Apple");
    print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>

//Output
Array
(
    [Apple] => 3
    [Banana] => 1
)
```